# Direct matrix multiplication in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, multiplication

can i write multiplication of matrix directly as    `rx=u[1][4]*m[4][4]*gx[4][4];` and how i have to initialize rx?
Is there any method to do direct product or any method which will not use loops?

Comment: If you know the dimensions in advance (and they're small), you can always unroll the loop, i.e. assign a direct value to each element. For example, result[0][0] = a[0][0] * b[0][0] + a[0][1] * b[1][0], in the case of 2x2 matrices.

Comment: What's wrong with loops?  Otherwise you will a specialized function for the specific array size.  Any time the array size changes, you will have to add more statements.

Comment: Indeed, but sometimes you do know the dimensions of the matrices you'll be working with. I'll go for loop-unrolling then...

Comment: A decent optimizing compiler may unroll loops for you, and _probably_ do a better job at it.

Comment: I think that your `[]` is to indicate the size of the matrices. I think it is unclear (as the real meaning is for the index...)

Comment: @icabod I can always take a peek at the assembly it generated. If I'm happy with it, then fine; otherwise I'll do it by myself. That way I'm always sure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your matrices are just arrays, then yes. By calling `matrix[x][y]` you are just accessing the variable stored at that location.

So if:

`u[1][4] == 2`

`m[4][4] == 8`

`gx[4][4] == 1`

then

`u[1][4] * m[4][4] * gx[4][4] = 16`

In regards to `rx`, it must be assigned to the same variable type, or one that can be implicitly casted to from what your matrices are storing (implicitly since I see no explicit casts in your example). So if your matrices are `float[][]` then `rx` should be a `float`.

There are also various math libraries that may do the work for you. See [Looking for an elegant and efficient C++ matrix library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359608/looking-for-an-elegant-and-efficient-c-matrix-library)